# Preenchimento de Cascade DropDownList e pegar dois campos

Tags: ajax, asp

Amigos boa tarde!!!

**1º** Tenho um arquivo (Repositório)em `ASP` que armazena meus `selects` para alguns `dropdowns`, neste tenho a função abaixo que lista minhas UF's:

```
public function ListarUF()
        dim sql
        dim cmd
        dim rs
        dim nota
        dim lista
        dim i

        sql = "SELECT * FROM UF ORDER BY UF"

        set cmd = ObterCommand(sql)

        set rs = cmd.Execute

        i = 0
        do while not rs.eof
            if i > 0 then
                lista = lista &  "|" & rs("UF")
            else
                lista = rs("UF")
            end if
            i = i + 1
            rs.moveNext
        loop
        rs.close

        set rs = nothing
        set cmd = nothing
        db.close

        ListarUF = lista
    end function
```

**2º** - tenho um outro arquivo em ASP que fazer menção o de cima para buscar a função em questão `ListarUF()` da seguinte forma:

no cabeçalho da página insiro o comando abaixo:

```
<!--#include file="Repositorios/RepositorioAsimov.asp"-->
```

em seguida crio o método abaixo:

```
caso "listarUF"  
  set repositorio = new clsRepositorioAsimov
  lista = repositorio.ListarUF()

  if err.number = 0 then
       Response.Write(lista)
  else
       Response.Write(err.Description)
  end if

  set lista = nothing
  set repositorio = nothing
```

**3º** - Na página que tenho que carregar o `Dropdown` insiro o código `ajax` abaixo:

```
function popularDropDownListUf() {
            $("#uf").empty();
            $("#uf").append("<option value='' selected></option>");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ServiceAsimov.asp?metodo=listarUF",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                async: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        var lista = response.split("|");

                        $.each(lista, function (key, value) {
                            $("#uf").append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
                        })
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, options, error) {
                    alert(error);
                    $(".loading").fadeOut();
                }
            });
}
```

O meu problema é que não estou conseguindo trazer o `Id` da `UF` e a Sigla da `UF` juntos, só está vindo para mim a sigla da `UF`.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Embora você esteja trazendo todos os dados da tabela,  está iterando apenas com a UF e não com a UF e o Id. O que você pode fazer é utilizar o recordset pra ler Id e concatenar o Id junto da UF, separando por outro caractere especial e dando split no javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte, concatenar o id no seu asp:

```
  public function ListarUF()
    dim sql
    dim cmd
    dim rs
    dim nota
    dim lista
    dim i

    sql = "SELECT * FROM UF ORDER BY UF"

    set cmd = ObterCommand(sql)

    set rs = cmd.Execute

    i = 0
    do while not rs.eof
        if i > 0 then
            lista = lista &  "|" & rs("UF") &"-"&rs("ID")
        else
            lista = rs("UF")
        end if
        i = i + 1
        rs.moveNext
    loop
    rs.close

    set rs = nothing
    set cmd = nothing
    db.close

    ListarUF = lista
end function
```

E então no javaScript, usar o split:

```
function popularDropDownListUf() {
        $("#uf").empty();
        $("#uf").append("<option value='' selected></option>");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ServiceAsimov.asp?metodo=listarUF",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    var lista = response.split("|");

                    $.each(lista, function (key, value) {
                     var ufDados = value.split("-");

                        $("#uf").append("<option value='" + ufDados[1]+ "'>" + ufDados[0]+ "</option>");
                    })
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, options, error) {
                alert(error);
                $(".loading").fadeOut();
            }
        });}
```